# ASP .NET 4 Wev Api controller - modify response type

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

Let’s say I’ve got a simple Web API controller. I want to return a basic .NET type as a result. For example:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Authenticate(LoginUserViewModel loginUserViewModel)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I’m getting different results in different browsers even if the request is exactly the same for all of them.
In Chrome and IE7 I get Content-Type in Response Headers as **application/json**; charset=utf-8, and response value equal to "**true**".
Firefox recognizes response Content-Type as **application/xml**; charset=utf-8 and sets response value to:

```
"<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>"
```

Is there any way to set response type on the server-side so it is always the same?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Here is JavaScript that I use to call my controller.

```
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                    async: false,
                    url: 'Login/Authenticate',
                    defaultHeaders: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
                    jsonData: user,
                    success: function (response, options) {
                        if (response.responseText !== 'true') {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Login failed, please try again');
                        } else {
                            document.location = 'Main.aspx';
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response, options) {
                        Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Server error. Cannot authenticate user.');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Could you show how are you invoking this controller action? You mentioned some browsers so I guess you wrote some javascript or something to invoke it. Could you show this javascript?

Comment: Sure. Will update my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because browsers send different Accept headers.  Web API uses the accept header to determine the content-type of the response.  By default Web API loads up a few different formatters into it's configuration.Formatters collection.

One way to force the response of to be a specific media-type is to remove all the existing formatters and add only the one you want.

```
configuration.Formatters.Clear();
configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! But it is still not clear for me why FF didn't pick up "Accept" attirbute from my header :( Please see js code above.

Comment: @BashirMagomedov  In those cases I would fire up Fiddler and watch exactly what FF is sending.  I didn't realize you were setting the accept header manually with JS.